# Have two separate JavaScripts act as one?

Tags: javascript, class, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

In my HTML, I have several pictures like this:

```
<img class="gallery_left" id="left4" src="assets/community/fall_regionals/img01.png" />
```

The image has a class and an ID.  I also have JavaScript for both the class gallery_left and ID left4:

```
$(function() {

    $('img.gallery_left').mouseover(function(){

        $(this).animate({
    borderWidth: '10px',
    width: '750px',
    height: '500px',
    marginLeft: '1px',
    zIndex: '15'}, 'default');

    });

    $('img.gallery_left').mouseout(function(){

        $(this).animate({
    borderWidth: '4px',
    width: '300px',
    height: '200px',
    marginLeft: '1px',
    zIndex: '0'}, 'default');

    });

    $('#left4').mouseover(function(){

        $(this).animate({
    marginTop: '105px'}, 'default');

    });

    $('#left4').mouseout(function(){

        $(this).animate({
    marginTop: '261px'}, 'default');

        });

    });
```

I have found that the JavaScript for the class gallery_left is executed first, then the ID left4.  In some cases they will execute (or at least appear to) simultaneously, but on mouseout the image will 90% of the time shrink in one action (class), and then move back down in another (ID).  I am finding this to be a big problem for many of my images.  Is there a way I can clean this up a little bit to make it more problem-free?  Also, suggesting to just make a specific class for each individual image to "combine" the two separate actions is out of the question, because that would be way too many classes.  Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need both the actions? What does your code do? Do you have different images with different ids, like left4?

Comment: I have a gallery of images, with 10+ rows of images with 3 images per row.  I have gallery_left, gallery_center, and gallery_right classes for images on the left side of each row, center, and right.  I have IDs specifically for each row specifying margin-tops, so that when somebody hovers over the image, the image grows proportionality upwards and downwards.

Comment: Then, my answer should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sWm6w/)

```
$(function() {
    var margin_top;

    $('img').mouseover(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('gallery_left')) {
            if($(this).attr('id') == "left4") {
                margin_top = '105px';
            } else {
                $(this).css('marginTop');
            }

            $(this).animate({
                borderWidth: '10px',
                width: '750px',
                height: '500px',
                marginLeft: '1px',
                zIndex: '15',
                marginTop: margin_top,
            }, 
            'default');
        } else if($(this).hasClass('gallery_right')) {
            if($(this).attr('id') == "right6") {
                margin_top = '105px';
            } else {
                $(this).css('marginTop');
            }

            $(this).animate({
                borderWidth: '10px',
                width: '750px',
                height: '500px',
                marginLeft: '199px',
                zIndex: '15',
                marginTop: margin_top,
            }, 
            'default');
        }
    });

    $('img').mouseout(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('gallery_left')) {
            if($(this).attr('id') == "left4") {
                margin_top = '261px';
            } else {
                $(this).css('marginTop');
            }

            $(this).animate({
                borderWidth: '4px',
                width: '300px',
                height: '200px',
                marginLeft: '1px',
                zIndex: '0',
                marginTop: margin_top,
            }, 
            'default');
        } else if($(this).hasClass('gallery_right')) {
            if($(this).attr('id') == "right6") {
                margin_top = '261px';
            } else {
                $(this).css('marginTop');
            }

            $(this).animate({
                borderWidth: '4px',
                width: '300px',
                height: '200px',
                marginLeft: '661px',
                zIndex: '0',
                marginTop: margin_top,
            }, 
            'default');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Like I said earlier, JavaScript is nearly foreign to me, but unfortunately I virtually have to use it for IE <10.  How would I apply this JavaScript to the many other pictures I have? (The ID's go left1, center2, right3, left4, center5, etc. in order from upper left corner to bottom right corner of the gallery)